# How to store DATE/TIME/YEAR in MySQL DATETIME field?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, database-design, time

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I can't seem to find an answer.

MySQL has these types of date/time types:

```
DATE:       0000-00-00
TIME:       00:00:00
DATETIME:   0000-00-00 00:00:00
TIMESTAMP:  0000-00-00 00:00:00
YEAR:       0000
```

I know one can use each of these datatypes to store each of them.

How can I store TIME only such as business opening/closing hours,YEAR only such as company year founded and DATE only such as date of birth within a DATETIME field? Thanks.

PS: Am using PHP, if that helps, though am looking for a pure MySQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you should store all of these as datetime. Hours of business can vary based on the day, and you may also need the day or month when a company was founded.

By storing everything as datetime it is possible that you would be persisting extra information.  But it would always be possible to easily retrieve the information of interest.  For example, to get the year a company was founded you could use either `YEAR(date_founded)`, or if you are feeling more sophisticated you could use `DATE_FORMAT('date_founded', '%Y')`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store timestamp and then use timestamp to get whatever information you want to retrieve from timestamp 
Based on language you are using there are available functions to help you with your implementation.
Share the language you are using so we can help you better

Comment: Avoid using `TIMESTAMP` because of its limited range. Use `DATETIME` and always store a UTC time (with `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` for example).

Comment: Sorry my mistake I meant to say UNIX timestamp